# Runnin Blender.exe vs. Blender-launcher.exe

Tags: modeling, windows

I am running v3.0.1 on a Windows 10 desktop.

When I open the folder where the Blender files are stored, which one do I open to run Blender: `Blender.exe` or `Blender-launcher.exe`?

Comment: Even if you are not an expert is it not normal for the soft to crash to desktop regularly. You may want to launch `blender_debug_log.cmd` instead, which will output a few txt files with some information relating to the state of blender when it crashed.

Answer (score 7):

You can use either of them as you prefer. The only difference I know is `blender-launcher.exe` prevents the command window from popping up when starting Blender.

Source: [Win: Add launcher to hide the console window flash · f3944cf503 - Blender Projects](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/commit/f3944cf503966a93a124e389d9232d7f833c0077)